# How do I set the actual file name of a file using HTML5 FileAPI?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently using the FileAPI of HTML5 to write some BLOB data to disk for offline usage.  I have told it to write to the file "test.mp4" but when finding the file on my computer, its filename is something like "00000003".  Everything works fine other than the file naming.  I can even access the file using the `getFile("test.mp4", ...)` command, so I know that it is working.  Is there a way to set the actual name of the file stored on disk?

**Edit:**

Here is part of my code:

```
function writeToFile(fs)
{
    fs.root.getFile("test.mp4", {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

            fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                console.log('Write completed.');
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
                console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
            };

            fileWriter.write(blobToWrite);

        }, errorHandler);

    }, errorHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the filename using `getFile()` by setting the `create` option to `true`:

`getFile('test.mp4', {create: true, exclusive: true}`

Check out this example: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-creatingempty

Comment: I was already there, and I based my code on their examples.  I have edited my question to show my file creation code.